# Swift OSX Call bash Script

Tags: swift, bash

I'm making a basic Mac app, that will make it easy to run a bunch of bash commands.
(Deply code, check uptime etc.. ) 
These I have written in bash scripts, and calling manually, they work great. 
I want to make it easier for my team.

I have made a button in Swift, calling an IB Action.

Then I run Process() on that script.
I then want to write the response to the call into a Scrollable text view.

The scripts are all in a folder in the app's code. say:

```
~/dev/ourapp/scripts/script1.sh
~/dev/ourapp/scripts/script2.sh
// etc...
```

And calling them from the cmd line there, they run fine.

The code I have is:

```
func run(_ command: String) -> String? {
        let pipe = Pipe()
    //    let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: command, withExtension: "sh")
        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: command, ofType: "sh")

        if(filePath == nil) {
            return  String(format:"Unknown Command: %@", command)
        } else {
            let process = Process()
            process.launchPath = String(format:"/bin/bash %@", filePath!)
            process.standardOutput = pipe
            let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
            process.launch()
            return String(data: fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8)
        }
    }
```

I then call it in my Action by:

```
    @IBAction func CallScript1(_ sender: NSButton) {

//        let response = run("~/dev/ourapp/scripts/script1")
        let response = run("script1")

        server_log.documentView!.insertText(response)

    }
```

The error I get:

> launch path not accessible

Thanks

Comment: you have to find the path for each script first.  `let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "script1", withExtension: "sh")`

Comment: Thanks @canister_exister - I've added that, but not clicking the button and fireing the action crashes the app. 
Can you please expand your answer?

Comment: If they are in a real folder in the bundle your URL will be nil

Comment: Thanks @matt - so I moved the script into the project root, and updated by code to check to the file, but always get nil?

Comment: It's not a matter of where it is the project, it's where it is in the built app bundle that matters.